# How to transform the Lambert conformal conic projection to latitude/longitude coordinates (WGS84)?

Tags: lambert-conformal-conic

I need to convert Lambert conformal conic projection to lat/long coordinates. My coordinate in Lambert is like this: (7678236.84856942, 1280719.40571689) and I expect to have a coordinate like Google numbers (something near to this: 45.4330538,-75.722731 for those numbers).

This page explains "Lambert conformal conic" which used with more details: https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/ref/dict/geo016-eng.cfm

On the Wikipedia page of LCC there is a transformation formula but I don't know what should be my parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is the "Canada" Lambert Conformal Conic, this is EPSG/SRID **102002**

You want your data in WGS84 which is EPSG/SRID **4326**

If you load your shapefile into QGIS, you can export it to another shapefile, and set the **input** and **output** coordinate systems in the export dialogue box.

Comment: May I ask how should I add shapefile to QGIS (Open and Import didn't support shapefile) and how to export it? I need a format to can be read by humans, like XML (not binary file).

Comment: What's the ultimate client of the data? Is it a google / leaflet map, or something else that requires the XML? The coordinates of the data can be written to columns in your existing shapefile without having to convert it, if that is you just need the numbers of the coordinates themselves...

Comment: If you want to have a record of the numbers, you can change the layer options in the output dialogue. You can save it as a CSV file to have all the numbers available.